# Loop Results When INNER JOIN Criteria Isn't Met

Tags: php, mysql

I have a SELECT statement that joins three tables (results, bets, usernames) up via a couple of INNER JOINS.  Here are the joins:

```
INNER JOIN bets b ON a.winner = b.horse 
INNER JOIN users c ON b.username = c.username
WHERE a.twitter_pubstatus = 0 AND a.market = '$win' AND b.type = '$userwin' 
AND a.date_dd = b.dd AND a.date_mm = b.mm GROUP BY a.winner");
```

I then have a php while loop below that loops all the results and winners if all the criteria is matched above.

What I am struggling with is that when the criteria of the joins isn't met I can't get the loop to display any result.  For example, in table a (results) there will always be a winner that gets entered every 15 minutes, but there might not be a matching bet on that winner in table b (bets).  So:

```
INNER JOIN bets b ON a.winner = b.horse
```

Will fall down.

What I am wanting:

1. Loop through all winner including there usernames if everything matches correctly. This works.
2. If b.horse doesn't exist it means nobody has won so I need it to just display the result.  This I can't get to work, how do I get this to just display all the results if there are no winners?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `INNER JOIN` only produces rows that have matches. If you want rows with no match, you have to use `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `LEFT JOIN` to get rows that have no matches.

```
SELECT *
FROM results a
LEFT JOIN bets b ON a.winner = b.horse AND b.type = '$userwin' AND a.date_dd = b.dd AND a.date_mm = b.mm
LEFT JOIN users c ON b.username = c.username
WHERE a.twitter_pubstatus = 0 AND a.market = '$win'
GROUP BY a.winner
```

If `b.horse` doesn't exist, the columns from `bets` will be `NULL`.

Comment: Within the while loop could I use: `if ($horse == NULL) {` Horse is defined earlier as `$horse = $row['horse'];` but I want to use some of the fields from the SELECT statement from table results.  Is this possible?

Comment: All the fields from `results` will be there. Only the fields from `bets` and `users` will be `NULL`.

Comment: I can't get it to show anything if horse == null.  There are 6 results in the database that should show as these aren't matched in the bets table.  Not sure why if as you say all the fields from results should be there.. Hmmm

Comment: What do you see when you print `$row['winner']` when $horse is null?

Comment: What if see if you just run the query by hand from the `mysql` command line tool or phpMyAdmin, rather than from PHP?

Comment: Ahh when I run my query it returns zero rows.  When I change a field in the results table (twitter_pubstatus = 0) that does have a matching user in bets then it shows 1 row as a result.

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle that demonstrates the problem? This should return rows for everything in `results` that matches `twitter_pubstatus = 0 AND market = $win`.

Comment: If you want any more help from me, make a sqlfiddle.

Comment: Ok thank you, you've pointed me in the right direction. Will make a sqlfiddle if I can't find the answer.  I have it now showing all from table but the one which matches is showing as null too. So close.  Thanks again for all your help :-)

Comment: Cracked it.  You were right. I left $userwin in! Thanks so much!

Comment: Do you mean you had `b.type = '$userwin'` in the `WHERE` clause instead of the `ON` clause? That would do it.

Comment: Yes, I had it in the WHERE instead of the ON.  Moved it to the ON and all the data came through from the results table including NULLS for the bets table and also matching criteria results. Perfect! Thanks again for your help, much appreciated.